# MSWord Vertical Align cells VBA from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am currently creating a function in excel which will create a table in MS word and fill in with data from excel, I am trying to format the table and having some issues with alignment.
I am trying to get the first two rows of each table made to vertically align in the center, and while it does not come up with an error, I don't see any change.

However when I run the same code in MS word directly, it works without any issues.
Code in Excel (word object is created as a word object, and tblnew is set to be a newly created table, other format changes with the table in the format work i.e font size, cell size and contents)

```
    with word
        with tblnew
            .Rows(1).Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalCenter
        end with
   end with
```

Running the following in the immediate window in word also works

```
    activedocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalCenter
```

If my understanding is correct, "tblnew" should already be referring to the "actidocument.tables(1)" so the code should be identicle, and the "with word" object should mean that the code is being executed in word as it would have been already, so im not sure where the issue lies.

Comment: `With Word` means nothing because there is no period before the `tblNew`. However, `Word` is a word reserved for the use of VBA. Therefore you should expect problems if you use it to name your variable. Name your Word.Application like `WdApp`. With that being said, when you use two applications you absolutely must declare each variable. For example, you declare your table as `Dim tblNew As Word.Table`. Then, when you refer to it, VBA will know that you mean a Word table and not an Excel table.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, 
Variables are all defined in the code before hand, I just hadnt included it,
tblnew is set as ".activedocument.Tables.Add(MyRange, 5, 13)" the "." being here is enough right?

I'll rename the variable for the word app, but I have been able to modify bits of the table already i.e merging cells and inputting data using the same things, it just seems to be the alignment causing problems

Comment: It isn't possible to tell you if the "." is correct or not without knowing what the "." refers to. If `.Activedocument` refers to `With Word` it is wrong. `Set` isn't the same as `Dim`. Once you have dimensioned the variable as `Dim tblNew As Word.Table` `tblNew` is a Word table and you don't have to mention it again. `Set tlbNew = Activedocument.Tables.Add` is adequate. But I would recommend to declare `Dim Doc As Word.Document` and then `Set Doc = ActiveDocument` for better clarity.

Comment: Remember, your code runs in an Excel environment. VBA will attempt to understand `ActiveDocument` as an Excel command, find that it doesn't exist, find that Word is also available and interpret it as a Word object. That takes time and can cause errors.

Comment: When manipulating tables, bear in mind that you lose the ability to refer to rows, if you have vertical merges, and columns, if there are horizontal merges. You should finish your entire table first and merge cells only when you are done - and you need to do the merging in such a way that you don't need to refer to rows after rows have been merged or to columns after columns have been merged. It's quite tricky. Most people who know how to do it recommend to abstain from merging. I don't know. Therefore I advise to be careful :-)

Comment: thanks for the detailed responses. i have the following

        'dim word as object',
       'set word = createobject("word.application")'
when i made the table i use
'with word Set tblnew = .activedocument.tables.Add(MyRange, 5, 13) end with'

If i am correct, it's basically saying word.activedocument.tables[...], so this should be correct still in recognising that the format is for word?

Comment: As you are using Late Binding I suspect that the problem is that Excel doesn't understand the constant wdAlignVerticalCenter. Replace that with its value, 1, and it may work better, assuming that there are no other errors in your code.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. After `Dim WdApp As Word.Application` `Dim Tbl As Word.Table` and `Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`, `Set Tbl = WdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(MyRange, 5, 13)` says, in plain text, Find the `ActiveDocument` of the WdApp application, add a table to it as specified by `(MyRange, 5, 13)` and assign that table's object to the declared variable `Tbl`, which means that all the new object's properties will be those defined in the still empty `Tbl` object. Of course this will fail if the new object and the `Tbl` space have different properties.

Comment: Observe that `MyRange` isn't defined in the above code. If you have a Dim statement like `Dim MyRange As Range` VBA (Excel) will assume this to be an `Excel.Range` which has different properties than a `Word.Range`. If you were to run the same code in VBA (Word), the same `Dim MyRange As Range` would be understood as defining a `Word.Range`. If you want to declare a `Word.Range` while running Excel's VBA you must use `Dim MyRange As Word.Range`. Observe that VBA is using the key word `Word`. If you try to compete with VBA for the use of that key word you are unlikely to win the argument.